# How to do a timeline with BC / BCE Years on Vis.js-timeline

Tags: vis.js-timeline

I've been trying to do a timeline of dates with **vis.js-timeline** that are BC or before 0.
Tried `start: '-0050-01-1'` and `start: '-50-01-1'` and they don't show.

Couldn't find documentation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So reading the object of [Expanded Years from ECMAScript 2022 Language Specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-expanded-years) found that:

> In the simplified ECMAScript format, such an expanded year
> representation shall have 6 digits and is always prefixed with a + or - sign.

Tried `'-000460-04-20'` and it shows as -460 (BC).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).